# Scrollable list of frames within canvas. After deleting a frame, space is added to the end of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4, tkinter-canvas

This is one issue I can't seem to figure out on my own. Here it is:

I have a scrollable list of frames that are all put within one larger frame, which is then packed within a canvas. Code is as follows:

```
### begin canvas/frame/picture 
self.picFrame = Frame(self, width = 450, height = 300)
        
self.picFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
self.picFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
self.picFrame.pack()
        
self.canvas = Canvas(self.picFrame, width = 450, height = 300)
self.canFrame = Frame(self.canvas)

self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window = self.canFrame, anchor = 'nw')
self.canvas.pack(side="left")
```

I create one frame which holds all the goodies, and then put that frame into `self.canFrame`:

```
self.itemFrame = Frame(self.canFrame, width = 450, height = 50)
self.itemFrame.grid(row = i, column = 0)
self.itemFrame.pack_propagate(0)
```

I also have some methods I call on the canvas to get it to scroll properly. They are as follows:

```
def setFrame(self, event = None):
    """ Sets the canvas dimensions and the scroll area """
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))


def setScroll(self):
    ##### part of another function #######
    # create frame to hold scrollbar so we can
    # use grid on the scrollbar
    self.scrollFrame = Frame(self.picFrame)

    # set rows and column configures so we can
    # make scrollbar take up entire row/column
    self.scrollFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
    self.scrollFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
    self.scroll = AutoScrollbar(self.scrollFrame,
                            orient = "vertical",
                            command = self.canvas.yview)

    # set scrollbar as callback to the canvas
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)

    # set the scrollbar to be the height of the canvas
    self.scroll.grid(sticky = 'ns', row = 1, column = 0)

    # set the scrollbar to be packed on the right side

    self.scrollFrame.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    # bind the picture frame to the canvas
    self.picFrame.bind("<Configure>", self.setFrame)
```

I also have a list which holds all of the frames that I put into the canvas,
and within each frame is a checkbox, so I can check if that box is selected and whether I want to delete it or not. When I delete the frame I call something along the lines of:

```
self.frames[i].destroy()
```

and that index coorresponds to the itemFrame that I want to destroy that holds all the goodies.

When I delete a frame I feel that I am missing resizing or removing that frame from another widget that may still 'remember' it. It all expands just fine, but when deleting the `itemFrames` is when I have an issue. I've tried for quite a while to figure this one out, but just can't seem to do it. Any hints or pointers on where to go from here would be great. I also apologize for this being a code heavy post, I wasn't exactly sure what would be needed or not. Thanks for bearing with me.

Cheers!

#### Edit/update:

I forgot to mention that I am using

```
to_del = self.frames.pop(i)
to_del.destroy()
```

and also resetting the scrollbar (to the best of my knowledge at least)

```
self.scroll.destroy()
self.scrollFrame.destroy()
self.setScroll()  # defined up above
```

does this still keep a reference even though I pop the specified frame?
Also, could it go all the way up to self.picFrame somehow? That's used to hold the canvas. If I delete all the items in the self.frames list, and try to update the list again, no images show up.

Edit - Also tweaked usage of 'pack' in sentences above. Shouldn't have been careless with that usage.

Comment: I don't see the assignment of `self.frames`, but note that `destroy()` will only destroy the widget, not delete its reference. If you want to do that, you'll have to do something like `del self.frames[i]`.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology. The word `pack` in the context of a question regarding layout means something very specific ("I called the pack function"), but you seem to be using it to mean "I added something" -- sometimes with pack, sometimes with create_window. It makes your question a bit hard to read.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I bet that's the problem. You might want to consider making an answer out of that comment.

Comment: Are you resetting the scrollregion attribute when you delete a frame?

Comment: I am using `scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all')` I've read the docs but don't quite understand what .bbox() means. I'll look into it more, although I don't see any questions right off the bat, maybe I'll make it a separate question.

Comment: That didn't answer the question. Are you configuring `scrollregion` _every time_ you remove something from the frame?

Comment: Yes. Every time I delete a frame I call `self.setScroll()` which ends up calling `self.setFrame` and then that sets `self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))`

Answer (score 0):

You've destroyed the frame with `self.frames[i].destroy()`, but the reference still exists in `self.frames`. To remove the reference from the `list`, use `del self.frames[i]`.